# How do I insert table from numpy into Mysql

Tags: python, mysql, numpy

I cant get the insert to work in this code.
I have other numpy to mysql that work fine. But there are no errors in running code. Mysql gives no errors. Using python 2.7 and pyodbc on winx64.

```
p = np.arange(1, 33, 3)
print p

def prow (f1,series):
    rowp=[]
    series = series.tolist()
    ss = series[8:]
    rowp.append(1)       
    rowp.extend(ss)         

    print len (rowp)
    print rowp
    print type(rowp)  

    InSQL  = 'INSERT INTO test._t VALUES (1, 25, 28, 31)' 
    print InSQL
    # csr.executemany(InSQL,rowp)
    csr.execute(InSQL)
    print 1234   
    cxn.commit

prow('foo', p)
```

MySql is below:

```
CREATE TABLE `_t` (
  `Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `T1` float(12,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `T2` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `T7` float(12,4) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

This print statements give;

```
[ 1  4  7 10 13 16 19 22 25 28 31]
4
[1, 25, 28, 31]
<type 'list'>
INSERT INTO test._t VALUES (1, 25, 28, 31)
1234
```

Using the "`INSERT INTO test._t VALUES (1, 25, 28, 31)`" in mysql shell works just fine. there is alot of redundant code, right now. The idea is to use executemany, but I cant the 
the simple code to work.

Comment: Where are declaring `csr` and `cxn`?

Comment: in the header which wasnt included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your commit is missing parens:

```
cxn.commit

# Should be:
cxn.commit()
```

Run from the interpreter, `cxn.commit` without parens simply returns a reference to the `commit()` method:

```
# Something like
>>> conn.commit
<built-in method commit of Connection object at 0x9cfe13c>
```

Comment: ok,but I change the InSQL  = 'INSERT INTO test._t VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', I still list error? And,  use executemany...

Comment: csr.executemany(InSQL,rowp)
TypeError: ('Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row', 'HY000')

Comment: use list(rowp) instead of rowp

Comment: tried, it didnt work. tried to use list(rowp) prior to executemany, didnt work